# Why my html file cannot connect to firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

1.I follow the instruction on the firebase document but it can not connect to the firebase successfully. I was trying to fetch the data from the firebase, but every time open the browser nothing shows on the page.

2.Here is my  code for connecting firebase

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Firebase Login</title>
 
</head>
<body>

  <h1 id = "1"></h1>
<!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->
 <p id = "2"> this is good </p>
  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

  
  <script>
    // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
    // For Firebase JavaScript SDK v7.20.0 and later, `measurementId` is an optional field
   var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDw09QqaJqy-wkbVpG3nJv-jUhgKEpW5fA",
    authDomain: "test-d9994.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://test-d9994-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "test-d9994",
    storageBucket: "test-d9994.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "552504009757",
    appId: "1:552504009757:web:90eaa489e604951adc12f4",
    measurementId: "G-RZRJ25E7GH"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  var bigOne = document.getElementById('2');
  var ref = firebase.database.ref().child('text')
  ref.on('value', snap=> bigOne.innerText = snap.val());
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine, read the documentation carefully `:)`

```
  var db = firebase.database().ref('text');

  db.get().then(function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  }
  else {
    console.log("No data available");
  }
```

This is full code (wrong call is commented):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Firebase Login</title>
 
</head>
<body>

  <h1 id = "1"></h1>
<!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->
 <p id = "2"> this is good </p>
  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

  
  <script>
    // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
    // For Firebase JavaScript SDK v7.20.0 and later, `measurementId` is an optional field
   var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDw09QqaJqy-wkbVpG3nJv-jUhgKEpW5fA",
    authDomain: "test-d9994.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://test-d9994-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "test-d9994",
    storageBucket: "test-d9994.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "552504009757",
    appId: "1:552504009757:web:90eaa489e604951adc12f4",
    measurementId: "G-RZRJ25E7GH"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  var bigOne = document.getElementById('2');
  //var ref = firebase.database.ref().child('text')
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('text'); // <--- right way call
  ref.on('value', snap=> bigOne.innerText = snap.val());

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, it seems to not work for me .. Do I need to add the node.js file?  I only create a HTML file.

Comment: This code just check that a connection works. Open condole by `F12`

Comment: Thanks, but there is no data on my HTML file?

Comment: you can do it inside `if` condition  `bigOne.innerText = snapshot.val()`

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering why this code can not connect to firebase....

Comment: your code is connecting, but you are using the wrong calls

Comment: Could you please tell me why I'm using the wrong calls? which part should I fix? thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229923/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-jay-parkkk).